# Log link of failed Hive job submitted to Dataproc through Airflow

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, airflow, google-cloud-dataproc, google-cloud-composer

I have submitted a Hive job using Airflow's [`DataprocWorkflowTemplateInstantiateInlineOperator`](https://airflow.apache.org/integration.html#dataprocworkflowtemplateinstantiateinlineoperator) to Dataproc cluster. When some of the jobs fail in googlecloud->dataproc->jobs I can see a link to the log with failure:

> Google Cloud Dataproc Agent reports job failure. If logs are available, they can be found in 'gs://dataproc-abcde12-efghi23-jklmn12-uk/google-cloud-dataproc-metainfo/12354a681fgh161/jobs/job1-abdc12jssa/driveroutput'

Can I fetch this log link (e.g. `gs://dataproc-abcde12-efghi23-jklmn12-uk/google-cloud-dataproc-metainfo/12354a681fgh161/jobs/job1-abdc12jssa/driveroutput`) through Airflow?

I checked [`gcp_dataproc_hook.py`](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/contrib/hooks/gcp_dataproc_hook.py) operator for anything that points to a log link so that I can retrieve it, but didn't find anything useful.

Comment: It appears this is already being logged: https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/contrib/hooks/gcp_dataproc_hook.py#L53

Answer (score 1):

Looks like there's no auto-created handy link to fetch the output in Airflow's logs yet, but it could certainly be added (if you're feeling bold, could be worth sending a pull request to Airflow yourself! Or otherwise filing a feature request https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AIRFLOW).

In general you can construct a handy URL or a copy/pasteable CLI command given the jobid; if you want to use Dataproc's UI directly, simply construct a URL of the form:

```
https://cloud.google.com/console/dataproc/jobs/%s/?project=%s&region=%s
```

with params

```
jobId, projectId, region
```

Alternatively, you could type:

```
gcloud dataproc jobs wait ${JOBID} --project ${PROJECTID} --region ${REGION}
```

A more direct approach with the URI would be:

```
gsutil cat ${LOG_LINK}*
```

with a glob expression at the end of that URL (it's not just a single file, it's a set of files).